# gitpython equivalent of git-apply

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Is there a way to apply a patch (in the form of a diff file) to a repo using only the gitpython library?

In other words, is there a gitpython equivalent of the git-apply command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to do

```
r = Repo('path-to-repo')
r.git.execute(['git','apply','patch.diff'])
```

I had tried this before but I had omitted the 'git' at the beginning of the argument list, which gave an error about the command not existing.

Comment: Is there no API in gitpython to do this directly? I am asking this because, most of the time we have a string which contains diff. In that case we will have to first write the diff to a file - then run `r.git.execute` and then clean up the file.

Comment: as far as i know there is nothing in the API. are you familiar with [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), I think that will make your scenario fairly painless

Answer (score 2):

You can use git directly, like this:

```
 repo = git.Repo('repository_path') 

 repo.git.apply(['-3', 'patch-file'])
```

this will perform the git command:

```
git apply -3 patch-file
```

Comment: Don't use links directly, try to paste some of the content to your answer!